# Load a PDF in a ActiveX widget

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to load a PDF into a `QAxWidget`:

```
self.axWidget = QAxContainer.QAxWidget()
self.axWidget.setProperty("geometry", QtCore.QRect(630, 20, 501, 651))
self.axWidget.setControl("Adobe PDF Reader")
self.axWidget.dynamicCall("LoadFile(const QString)", "test.pdf")
```

However, it only loads an empty gray background:
[image]

I've been searching for alternatives, external libraries, python pdf-to-png libraries and then just simply load an image, etc. But every result I found so far seems overkill for this task.

So, since Qt actually supports ActiveX controls, where can I check a working example, or the specific documentation for dynamicCalls from Python in order to load the PDF inside a [QAxWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaxwidget.html)?

I only need it as read-only data, so even an Image of it would work.

Comment: Try it with: `self.axWidget.dynamicCall("LoadFile(const QString &)", full_path_to_pdf_file)`. Also, you might want to check the return value of `setControl` (i.e. it should be `True`).

Comment: I add a comment to this question that seems popular over the years: use a QWebEngineView to load PDFs instead, it makes it infinitely a lot more easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation and I was not able to "simply" show a pdf file in my application windows.

After a lot of tests and attempts I have found a workaround that works for me.

Instead of load the control `"Adobe PDF Reader"`, that use Adobe Acrobat PDF API (AcroPDF64.dll), I load the control `"Microsoft Web Browser"` that use the dll of Internet explorer (ieframe.dll).

Here the code that I used:

```
pdf = QAxWidget("Microsoft Web Browser")
pdf.dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", pdf_path)
self.Ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(pdf)
```

First I create with Qt Designer a `verticalLayout` container in my `Ui`.

Then I create a `QAxWidget` instance in which I load the control `"Microsoft Web Browser"`.

After saving in `pdf_path` variable, full path of my pdf file, I `Navigate` in the Web Browser at my pdf full path.

At the end I add the `QAxWidget` into `verticalLayout`.

In this way the pdf file it is visualized with Microsoft Web Browser default plugin, that is Acrobat Reader DC in my case.

To refresh or initialize the `QAxWidget`, i.e. for change pdf file or automatic refresh the content I use this solution:

```
for i in reversed(range(self.Ui.verticalLayout.count())):
    self.Ui.verticalLayout.itemAt(i).widget().dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", "")
    self.Ui.verticalLayout.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()
    self.Ui.verticalLayout.itemAt(i).widget().destroy(True)
```

This `for` cycle empties my `Ui.verticalLayout`.

Comment: Would Microsoft web browser work on a linux or mac? I am wondering.