# Embed Acrobat Reader into PyQt5 Application leads to blank pages [PyQt5]

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt, pyqt5, activex

## Problem description and context

I'm trying to make an application that allows to fill numerous numbers of forms and then parse the filled data and link it to a database. In order to use all the company's already made PDF forms, I wanted to embbed the acrobat reader in my PyQt application, since it is a attractive and fully functionnal PDF interaction software. But, after I set my QAxWidget to Adobe PDF Reader, the backgroud becomes grey (as if it had loaded acrobat), but any command I send to the QAxWidget doesn't seem to work.

## **Minimal Working Example**

I cannot find any true documentation for linking acrobat reader with pyqt5 applications. I added a QAxWidget, then I added it as my centralWidget. Then, in the function called OpenBlank(), I used the same functions I found on every website to Load the PDF with acrobat. ***The Important Part*** is really the **openBlank()** function. All the other stuff is just to make the MWE work. Just add any PDF file and change the path name to yours. You'll see it stays empty.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.AxViewer = QAxWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.AxViewer)
        self.openBlank()

    def openBlank(self):
        FormPath = "a.pdf"
        self.AxViewer.clear()
        if not self.AxViewer.setControl('Adobe PDF Reader'):
            return QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', 
    'Adobe PDF Reader is not installed on your computer.')

        self.AxViewer.dynamicCall("LoadFile(const QString&)", FormPath)
        self.AxViewer.dynamicCall("setShowScrollbars(bool)", "True")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## **Expectations**

The result should open the file and turn on the scroll bar, but instead I get an empty background. It is similar to [Load a PDF in a ActiveX widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751646/load-a-pdf-in-a-activex-widget) question, but I decided to duplicate it as it hasn't been answered in over a year.

Comment: Try replacing: 
    `self.AxViewer.dynamicCall("LoadFile(const QString&)", FormPath)` , 
    `self.AxViewer.dynamicCall("setShowScrollbars(bool)", "True")` 
on: 
    `self.AxViewer.dynamicCall('LoadFile(FormPath)')`

Comment: doesn't do anything. You can try it on your own, since i've made a MWE for that purpose

Comment: Funny, I've found this question... with a link to my own question from 3 years ago... and yet, here I am again. Stuck at this madness. Qt should display PDF more easily, like built-in. Anyway, were you able to find a way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with `self.AxViewer.dynamicCall()`. I manage to find some samples with C++ how to use this

```
AxViewer = new QAxWidget(this);
----------------
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    //AxViewer->dynamicCall("LoadFile(\"D:\\OneDrive\\Documents\\sample.pdf\")");
    AxViewer->dynamicCall("LoadFile(QString)",
                     QDir::toNativeSeparators(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                                           "Open PDF File",
                                                                           QDir::currentPath(),
                                                                           "PDF Documents (*.pdf)")));
}.
```

Someone could convert it into Python. I am not familiar with C++.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare your widget as MS Web Browser:

```
self.axWidget = AxWidget('Microsoft Web Browser')
```

and call it like this:

```
self.dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", path)
```

it works. You must also return from your calling point or the gui got stuck:

```
        if extension == ('.pdf'):
            self.scrollArea.setLayout(self.layout)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.axWidget)
            self.thread =  threading.Thread(target=self.axWidget.open_pdf(path))
            self.thread.start()
            return
```